# Interchanging lim sups

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose I have a sequence of real functions $f_n(x) $ which are upper semicontinuous for each $n$. I want to find criteria such that I can have $$\limsup_n \limsup_{y\to x} f_n(x) = \limsup_{y\to x} \limsup_n f_n(x).$$
Any help at all is appreciated.
 I would also like to know if it holds with the equality replaced by an inequality!